# Serialize of 1+n objects from 2 models, that do not have relationships

Tags: django, python-3.x, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have 2 modules in 2 different apps *that are not in relationship of any kind*:

```
class Table(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    columns = JSONField()

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
```

I need to create Serializer, that first of all serialize only 1 specific  Table object (always the same). For example it musk be Table.obejects.get(id=1). And then I serialize Company according to content in View function, that I had posted bellow.

That scenario is very important, because in **Table** I explain how to build table, and in **Company** I get data, that I'll put in pre-build table.

Serializer class for Company:

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('name',)
```

View class for Company:

```
class CompanyList(APIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Company.objects.all()

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        companies = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = CompanySerializer(companies, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is *merge 2 separate serializes in one response*.

For that you need to have 2 prepared serializers:

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('name',)

class TableSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Table
        fields = ('columns',)
```

Then *Response* them as list:

```
class CompanyList(APIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Company.objects.all()

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        companies = self.get_queryset()
        company_serializer = CompanySerializer(companies, many=True)
        table_serializer = TableSerializer(Table.objects.get(name='customers.company'))

        return Response([table_serializer.data, company_serializer.data])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create separate `TableSerializer`:

```
class TableSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Table
        fields = ('name',)
```

And use it inside `CompanySerializer` with [`SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield):

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    table = SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('name',)

    def get_table(self, obj):
        table = self.context['table']
        return TableSerializer(table).data
```

In view you need to add `table` to serializer [context](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context):

```
class CompanyList(APIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Company.objects.all()

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        companies = self.get_queryset()
        table = Table.obejects.get(id=1)
        serializer = CompanySerializer(companies, many=True, context={'table': table})
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. The only problem is that it repeat data from 'table' in each Company object. But there is no need for that. Table suppose to be serialized just 1 time in the beginning, to show UI how to build table.